# jQuery-ui conflicting with CarouFredSel

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, caroufredsel

So, I'm trying to build a webpage that will include jQuery-ui tabs, and each tab will have a differently-populated carousel within. After doing a bunch of research, the issue seems to be that CarouFredSel's tabs conflict with jQuery-ui's tabs (or something).

I'm very new to `JQuery/js/CSS/HTML/Ruby on Rails`, so I'm having a lot of trouble resolving this.

Right now, I'm just trying to get this example to work: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/8/

But the tabs remain completely absent. Another StackOverflow question told me to use "!important" on the `display: block` line to override jQuery-ui, which defaults to hidden apparently, but that hasn't worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src=<%= asset_path( "jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js" ) %></script>
  <script src=<%= asset_path( "jQuery.js" ) %></script>

  <style>

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    min-height: 600px;
}
body * {
    font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 22px;
}

#wrapper {
    background-color: #F4F0EE;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 275px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    margin: -150px 0 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;

}
#tabs > div {
    width: 700px;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#tabs img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 25px 0 0;
    float: left;

}
#tabs h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 60px 0 20px 0;

}

#pager {
    width: 700px;
    margin: -76px auto 25px auto;
    text-align: center;

}
#pager a {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-color: #ccc;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 30px;

}
#pager a:hover {
    color: #666;

}
#pager a:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;

}
#pager a.selected {
    background-color: #F4F0EE;
    color: #333;

}

#tabs #blue img {
    margin-top: 30px;

}
#tabs #pink img {
    margin-top: 0;
}
#tabs #white img {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#source {
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -200px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;

}
#source, #source a {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 12px;

}

  </style>
  <script>
$(function() {
    $('#tabs').carouFredSel({
        circular: false,
        items: 1,
        width: '100%',
        auto: false,
        pagination: {
            container: '#pager',
            anchorBuilder: function( nr ) {
                return '<a href="#">' + $(this).find('h3').text() + '</a>';
            }
        }
    });
});
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="tabs">
        <div id="blue">
            <img src=<%=  asset_path( "blue_muffin.png" ) %> alt="blue_muffin" width="148" height="185" />
            <h3>Cupcake ipsum</h3>
            <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet pie pudding tiramisu. Powder biscuit oat cake jelly-o jelly beans danish cookie. Jelly carrot cake topping souffl&eacute; topping brownie apple pie lemon drops sweet roll. Gummi bears danish lollipop. Jelly-o chocolate bar halvah jelly beans. Bonbon sesame snaps wafer. Applicake croissant donut sugar plum drag&eacute;e. Sweet oat cake danish.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="pink">
            <img src=<%=  asset_path( "light_pink_muffin.png" ) %>  alt="light_pink_muffin" width="151" height="245"/>
            <h3>Sesame snaps</h3>
            <p>Sesame snaps tootsie roll donut. Sweet roll candy canes chocolate bar wafer sweet roll gummies topping gummi bears. Pudding cheesecake cookie. Muffin sweet roll tart tart muffin. Pastry pudding marshmallow cupcake cake toffee toffee bonbon topping. Apple pie cupcake caramels. Icing chocolate bar lemon drops caramels bonbon bear claw.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="white">
            <img src=<%=  asset_path( "white_muffin.png" ) %>  alt="white_muffin" width="144" height="153"/>
            <h3>Apple pie jelly</h3>
            <p>Apple pie jelly gingerbread gummies topping. Gingerbread jelly marshmallow oat cake wafer lollipop. Cupcake chocolate cake apple pie. Caramels lollipop croissant bear claw brownie carrot cake wafer halvah lollipop. Candy canes tootsie roll jelly-o. Liquorice sugar plum sweet icing tiramisu.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p id="source">Source: <a href="http://cupcakeipsum.com" target="_blank">cupcakeipsum.com</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I realize the code looks a little rough; I've been testing, copying, and removing a lot of things. I can clean it up if it's an issue.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you using !important or important!? The Exclamation mark should come first, not after the word important

Comment: Sorry, I was using "!important". I'll edit the first post to reflect that.